# R: fill nodes in a network graph using a lookup table

Tags: r, graph, igraph, ggnet2

I would like to fill all the nodes in `edges$from` that belong to the same `groups$group` with the same color. How can I do that? Thanks for help!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(GGally)

edges <- data.frame(from = c("A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "F", "F", "H", "I", "K", "J", "B", "I", "B", "L", "L"),
                    to   = c("E", "A", "A", "A", "G", "G", "C", "G", "G", "J", "K", "I", "B", "G", "K", "K"))

groups <- data.frame(node =  "A", "B", "D", "E", "C", "F", "H", "G", "I", "K", "J", "L",
                     group = "1", "1", "1", "E", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE)

ggnet2(igraph::simplify(g), label = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `c()` to wrap the columns in the data.frame `groups`, i.e.,

```
groups <- data.frame(
    node = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "C", "F", "H", "G", "I", "K", "J", "L"),
    group = c("1", "1", "1", "E", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3")
)
```

Then, without `ggnet2`, functions in `igraph` are sufficient to help .you to reach the goal. For example

```
edges %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE) %>%
    simplify() %>%
    set_vertex_attr(
        name = "grp",
        value = with(groups, factor(group[match(names(V(.)), node)]))
    ) %>%
    plot(vertex.color = V(.)$grp)
```

[image]